# Unable to change my textfield value in material-ui with formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have the below code where I am setting a default value using the material-ui Textfield API within a formik fieldarray:

```
<TextField
   name={`myGroups.${index}.myGroupName`}
   value={`Group ${index+1}`}
   label="Group"
   InputProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: "white" }}}
   autoComplete="off"
   onChange={(e) => setFieldValue(`myGroups.${index}.myGroupName`, e.target.value)}
/>
```

Unfortunately with the above code, I am not able to change the value at all against this textfield. It seems to be read-only.

I have added the `onChange` call to update the Formik iniitial states values but to no avail.

Just can't seem to update the value.

Unsure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I found a working tutorial using material ui + formik here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAvkbSYdyRU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are are passing a hard-coded string to the `values`. You are supposed to map the corresponding value of each field.

```js
<TextField
  name={`myGroups.${index}.myGroupName`}
  value={values.myGroups[index].myGroupName}
  label="Group"
  InputProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: "white" } }}
  autoComplete="off"
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Please see the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-archimedes-85quw?file=/src/App.js:339-392

Comment: I will take a look but the whole idea is that I need to default this field to `Group ${index+1}` - Group 1 and when the user presses the `Add Group` button then default the new field to `Group ${index+1}` - Group 2 etc, at the same time, allowing the user to overwrite this default value.

Comment: Having a closer look, it all looks fine but is there a means off appending the [index] value to the end of `value={values.myGroups[index].myGroupName}` so I get Group 1, Group 2 etc ?

Comment: Yes, you can use template string for that:
```js
value={`$values.myGroups[index].myGroupName} ${index+1}`}
```

Comment: For setting a default or initial value for the fields, you can use `mapPropsToValues` of the Formik.

Comment: I tried `value={`${values.myGroups[index].myGroupName} ${index+1}`}` but when I press the backspace key, strange things happen in the field - the number 1 always appears. Pls try on your codesandbox. Also new to Formik and unsure how to use `mapPropsToValues`

Comment: any ideas pls re: backspace key issue?

Comment: I have updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-archimedes-85quw?file=/src/App.js). Pleas have a look.

Regarding the initial/default values, you can use either [initialValues](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#initialvalues-values) of <Formik> wrapper component. Or if you are using `withFormik` wrapper, you can use [mapPropsToValues](https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik#mappropstovalues-props-props--values). You can get more details about those in formik documentation.

Comment: Appreciate the update. Just a heads up, within my screen, the first group is already presented to the user, i.e. `Group 1` is already visible prior to the user pressing the `Add Group` button and unfortunately I'm not sure if I can use `myGroupName: `Group ${values.myGroups.length + 1}`. Is there a means of you changing your sandbox to accommodate my scenario - thanks.

Comment: You can accomplish that by updating the initial values.
```mapPropsToValues: () => ({
    myGroups: [{ myGroupName: "Group 1" }]
  })
```

Comment: just wondering if you are able to look at this new SO thread re: something similar to this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007279/target-formik-initial-values-state-array-element-using-setfieldvalue-to-set-a-de