# Target formik initial values state array element using setFieldValue to set a default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have the following Formik setup wrt to initial values:

```
    const emptyAreaPayload = {
             name: null,
             areaInfo: [
               {
                  areaName: "Area 1",
                  areaCode: null
               }
             ]
    }

   const emptyAreaInfo = {
            areaName: "Area 1",
            areaCode: null
   }
```

I then have my initialvalues setup as follows:

```
const INITIAL_VALUES = {
  taskName: '',
  taskNotes: '',
  areaGroups: [emptyAreaPayload]
};
```

My question is, as part of a `FieldArray` setup with **Add Area/Remove Area** buttons, when the user enters info regarding `areaInfo` where the first instance of the record presented to the user for `areaName` defaults to "Area 1", I want to be able to then default the next record, when the user presses the **Add Area** button to "Area 2" etc.

I have tried the following but I'm unsure how to target `areaInfo[].areaName` using below `setFieldValue` value as I need to get to the lowest array within `areaGroups`.

Just not sure what the continuation of `${values.areaGroups.length}` should be to hit `areaName`?

```
             <Button       
               onClick={() => {
                arrayHelpers.push(emptyAreaInfo)  
                formikProps.setFieldValue(                                                    
                   `areaGroups.${values.areaGroups.length}.areaInfo`,
                   `Area ${values.areaGroups.length + 1}`
                )}
               }     
            >
              Add Area
            </Button>
```

Pls note here that `values` holds all my initial values state.